# Is one using-statement enough for all variables pointing to one IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, idisposable, sqlcommand

**Such as so**: Creating it in a method and assigning it to a field. Passing that field to a method and then assigning it to a variable of a using-statement (Which is the only `Dispose` being called).

```
SqlCommand CreateSqlCommand()
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    return cmd1;
}

void UseSqlCommand(SqlCommand cmd4)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd3 = cmd4)//Is this using-statement enough?
    {
        //use cmd3 here...
    }
}
```

And used:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = CreateSqlCommand();
UseSqlCommand(cmd2);
```

**Extra detail**: Will the GC collect all of these variables on its next round or not? Why not - see David M. Kean's answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/916a1734-3e19-43a1-95c7-e3a2cd18369d/should-i-call-dispose-on-a-sqlcommand-object).

**EDIT**

I've added

```
cmd2.CommandText = "";
```

after the previous (last) line. And there's no error thrown.

Why? It should be disposed already! **Never mind**. A disposed object can be referenced...

**Please do not concentrate on the example, rather do - on the question itself. Thanks.**

Comment: That looks reaaally bad. assuming that the CLR will call `Dispose()` at the end of the `using` block, you will have some `cmd4` object reference pointing to an already-disposed object. Please don't do that.

Comment: agreed; you'd have to check to see if it's not disposed each time like HighScore said.

Comment: @HighCore I'm trying to create a method to execute any command. So it receives an already-made command.

Comment: @HighCore `cmd4` appears those two times _only_. And the same goes for `cmd2`.

Comment: @ispiro you didn't understand, did you? variable names are irrelevant. Your object instance is COMING from SOMEWHERE ELSE, and your method is calling `Dispose()` on it. Whatever other method that called this method will have this instance disposed. This is very Exception-prone.

Comment: I would create Connection (not command).  Pass the closed connection.  In the UseSqlConn open and close the connection in a try catch finally.

Comment: You could instantiate any number of SqlCommand variables (well, references actually) and assign them all (directly or indirectly) from the same CreateSqlCommand, and they will all reference the same SqlCommand object. Your using method will dispose of the underlying object, so all the references will become invalid. I suppose the literal answer to your question is yes, but it is, as HighCore says not good. You are basically defeating the purpose of using... might just as well do away with the using and call Dispose yourself in the "use" method... again... doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the using statement will call Dispose() after the block has completed on the referenced variable. This is a good and bad thing, suppose that you create a sql command and store the result in a variable `cmd`, then you pass that variable to another method that uses and disposes `cmd`. Now you are stuck with a variable that is disposed, and if you try to use it, it might throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCommand();
UseSqlCommand(cmd);

//Uh oh, cmd can still be used, what if I tried to call UseSqlCommand(cmd) again?
```

It would be more clear and secure to dispose of that object outside of the method(Like Jordão posted).

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCommand())
{
    UseSqlCommand(cmd);
}
```

Now you completely control the object and limit it's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Control the scope of `using` from outside:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = CreateSqlCommand()) {
  UseSqlCommand(cmd2);
}

...

void UseSqlCommand(SqlCommand cmd4) {
  // use cmd4 here...
}
```

And maybe rename `UseSqlCommand` to something different, like `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I'm still wondering about the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `using` statement is not to dispose of *variables*, but rather *object instances*.  Variables are often used for the purpose of identifying object instances, but reference-type variables don't hold object--they hold "object identifiers".

If one says e.g. `var myPort = new System.Io.Ports.SerialPort("COM1", ...); myPort.Open()`, the `SerialPort` object will ask the system to let it use the `COM1` serial port *and not let anyone else use it until further notice*.  The system will generate a handle for that port, and set some flags so that only code which has that handle will be allowed to use the port.  Once the object is created (say the system arbitrarily assigns it an ID of #8675309), the system will store that ID into the variable `myPort`).

When code no longer needs to use that serial port, it is important that someone tell object #8675309 that it is no longer needed, so it can in turn tell the system that it should make COM1 available to other applications.  This would typically be done by calling `Dispose` on a variable which holds a reference to object #8675309.  Once that is done, every variable that holds a reference to object #8675309 will hold a reference to an object whose `Dispose` method has been called.  Note that the `Dispose` method won't actually affect any of those variables (unless they are rewritten within the code of the method itself).  Any variables which held "object #8675309" before the call will continue to do so after.  The object will have released its serial port, so the reference which is stored those variables will no longer be useful for much, and the code that uses those variables may want them to be cleared, but the `SerialPort` object won't care one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
public class MySqlClass : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection conn { get; set; }

    public MySqlClass(string connectionstring) 
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    }

    public void DoSomething1(string tsql)
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(tsql, conn)) {
            conn.Open();           
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething2(string tsql)
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(tsql, conn)) {
            conn.Open();           
        }
    }

    //DISPOSE STUFF HERE    
}
```

Use...

```
using (MySqlClass MySQL = new MySqlClass()) 
{
    MySQL.DoSomething1();
    MySQL.DoSomething2();
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
Updated >>>> EXAMPLE <<<<< Point is you create single instance of SqlConnection above, and you can resuse it.  The class implements IDisposable so you can use the using() method to auto dispose.  Better than passing instances of SqlCommand like you mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why have the cmd field? It's completely ignored in the code you mentioned!

Comment: Updated my example - example!